# Javascript variable values used for URL generation not evaluating as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to pass a string from a `"text"` field to an MVC action. The form variable is called `query`. The Javascript code is:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="search..." 
name="SearchBar" onkeypress="searchfunction()" />
<script>
function searchfunction()
{
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        var url = '"' + document.getElementById("#SearchBar").value + '"';
        window.location = "@Url.Action("~/Home/Search")?query=" + url;

    }
}
</script>
```

The URL generated from this should be `domain/Home/Search?query=[contents of textfield]` but for some reason it's generating a URL like `domain/search.html?SearchBar=[contents of SearchBar]` and I get `0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference`. I am sure those two are related, but `.value` is what EVERY example I can find recommends using.

Note: I tried using the `getElementById` both with `#` and without, same for the `name` property of the input.

Should I just be passing the string in the `onkeypress` event? Am I missing something simple? Is this a bug in MVC 3?

Comment: The "id" attribute in input tag is missing, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
document.getElementById("SearchBar").value
```

the previous notation comes from jquery.you cannot use them interchangeably.If you prefer the jquery way that would be

```
$("#Searchbar").val();
```

and add an id = "Searchbar" to the textfield.

Comment: that got rid of the error, but what in my string assembly process is telling it that there should be ".html" anywhere in that string? 

there aren't even HTML files on this server. whole thing is running with MVC routes.

Answer (score 3):

Add the "id" attribute:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="search..." 
  name="SearchBar" id="SearchBar" onkeypress="searchfunction()" />
```

And remove the "#" character from `getElementById()` method param

Answer (score 1):

You Define `getElementsById()` So If you select name from any html element you have to ..Use :

`getElementsByName()` ,*Its return Array not a particular element as you want to select*.

In your Case ( because you use `#` inside get function, i assume you have to get ID )

**`#` = ID selector used In `JQuery` not in pure javascript.**

apply ID of your Element :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="search..." 
name="SearchBar" id='SearchBar' onkeypress="searchfunction()" />
<script>
 function searchfunction()
 {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    var url = '"' + document.getElementById("SearchBar").value + '"';
    window.location = "@Url.Action("~/Home/Search")?query=" + url;

  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: ...except it's not `getElementById("#SearchBar")`; should be `getElementById("SearchBar")`.

Comment: @AshishMishra +1, would have marked this one had I refreshed and seen the comments.

Comment: its Ohk .. :) @Originalmouse